# GET Request for GPX "Resource not found" Strava API

Tags: python, api, get-request, strava

Following Stravas API instructions [Export Route GPX (getRouteAsGPX)](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Routes-getRouteAsGPX), we do not get the gpx file.

The code we used is:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import gpxpy
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

auth_url = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token"
activites_url = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities"
gpx_url= "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/routes/%s/export_gpx" .format(4947441661)


access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
print("Access Token = {}\n".format(access_token))

header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
param = {'per_page': 200, 'page': 1}
response = requests.get(gpx_url, headers=header, params=param).json()
```

We receive a dic back, but without the gpx file.
{'message': 'Resource Not Found', 'errors': []}

Has anyone succesfully retrieved the gpx file lately? Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your `gpx_url` line with the line below did the trick for me. Make sure you have access to route 4947441661 and have the appropriate scope (read_all).

```
gpx_url= "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/routes/%s/export_gpx" % 4947441661
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I had the activity and route concepts mixed, I thought they were the same, but obviously no. 
I was requesting an activity instead of a route. That was my mistake.